# How to intelligently resolve WinTabMex error in Psychtoolbox on Windows 7?

Tags: methodology

While piloting a task in psychtoolbox and exiting via (ctrl-c --> sca), I receive this error:

> Error using WinTabMex Tried to initialize WinTab, but it is already
>   initialized! Call code 1 (Shutdown) first!

How do I call code 1 or otherwise intelligently resolve this error? 
Restarting MATLAB fixes the problem, but it seems like a brute-force solution.